# GPars forkOffChild exception handling

Tags: groovy, gpars

I'm using GPars' fork/join.  When I throw an exception after calling forkOffChild, it gets buried.

For example:

```
def myRecursiveClosure = { boolean top ->
    try {
        if (!top) {
            throw new RuntimeException('child had a problem')
        } else {
            forkOffChild(false)
        }
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        println 'Exception handled internally'
        throw exc
    }
}

try {
     GParsPool.withPool {
         GParsPool.runForkJoin(true, myRecursiveClosure)
    }
} catch (Exception exc) {
     println 'Exception handled externally'
     throw exc
}
```

Here, I set a flag so I know the closure has been called recursively.  Then, I throw an exception, which gets caught 'internally', but the re-throw is never caught 'externally'.  So I am not aware that the forked child failed.

I tried the exception handler also, but it doesn't seem to get called either.

Is this expected behavior, or am I doing something wrong?  Are there any strategies to help with this?  I can't have the child silently fail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important piece here is that forkOffChild() doesn't wait for the child to run. It merely schedules it for execution. So you cannot expect the forkOffChild() method to propagate exceptions from the child, since they are likely to happen long after the parent has returned from the forkOffChild() method.

Typically, however, a parent is interested in the outcome of the child computations, so it at some point after forking off collects the results using the getChildrenResults() method. This gives you back a list of calculated values or re-throws potential exceptions.

This snippet shows a minimal change to get the expected behavior:

```
   try {
        if (!top) {
            throw new RuntimeException('child had a problem')
        } else {
            forkOffChild(false)
            println childrenResults
        }
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        println 'Exception handled internally'
        throw exc
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!  I and looked at your examples, Vaclav, and saw this.

Comment: Ugh got timed out there.  Your explanation makes sense.  I tried it and it worked.  I'm assuming this is the right approach for async functions also.  After testing, I can see that parallel collections do throw it up to the caller, I assume they are doing this sort of 'get result' internally.  They seem to eventually die, I guess there's no good way to instantly kill all the threads though if one gets an exception?

Comment: Well, there's a related problem here... whenBound doesn't throw an exception up like a get() does, and the closure code doesn't get called.  How do you handle exceptions with async functions and whenBound?  If you like, I'll post a separate question.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, parallel collections do not cancel ongoing calculations, if an exception occurs.

Comment: An asynchronous function will bind the exception to the returned promise and so get() will re-throw it and whenBound() will pass it to the handler:
result.whenBound{if (it instanceOf Exception) ... }

Comment: Well, thanks, I tried that, but it never seems to get inside whenBound.  I am using version 0.12, do I need a newer version?

Comment: I guess 0.12 should be just fine. Does the following code print the exception?

withPool {

 {->throw new RuntimeException('test')}.asyncFun().call().whenBound {println it}
   
}

Comment: Are you certain the exception gets propagated outside of your function?

Comment: Your code there is essentially what I tried.  Inside the async function I intentionally threw an exception.  If I do a promise*.get() on the results, the exception is discovered in the main thread and thrown back up.  If I put a println or breakpoints inside the whenBound, they never happen.  I did notice that I got a runtime exception initially b/c I had typed my whenBound closure argument to boolean, so I thought it would work as you suggested above, and removed the type, rather using 'it'.  But as mentioned it never seems to get inside the whenBound closure.

Comment: I checked that older GPars versions also correctly pass the exception into the whenBound() handler. ATM I have no idea why your handler doesn't get invoked.